# Web API 2 - IIS7 POST method. 405 - not allowed after trying all possible solutions I could find

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-7, http-post

My test application was developed using Vs 2013 web application empty template using Web Api.

This is what my routing initialization looks like:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.EnableCors();

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

This is what my controller looks like:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Route ("Test")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Response to get Request";
    }

    [Route("Test")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post(string text)
    {
        return string.Format("Received: '{0}'", text);
    }
}
```

This is what my web.config file looks like after including all suggested fixes:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet" />
      <add name="HttpPost" />
      <add name="HttpPut" />
      <add name="HttpDelete" />
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <verbs allowUnlisted="false">
        <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
        <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
        <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
        <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
      </verbs>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>

  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

I have verified the Handler Mappings and Requests Filtering of my application using IIS manager and the POST verb shows up as enabled.

I have traced the requests rejected by ISS and I found that the ManagedPipeLineHandler sets the 405 error as seen below:

> ModuleName ManagedPipelineHandler
>
> Notification 128
>
> HttpStatus 405
>
> HttpReason Method Not Allowed
>
> HttpSubStatus 0
>
> ErrorCode 0
>
> ConfigExceptionInfo
>
> Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
>
> ErrorCode The operation completed successfully. (0x0)

My assumption is that the request doesn't go to my application. Am I correct?

I have been testing using Fiddler and I found that the Response Headers have a section named 'Security' with a single line reading 'Allow: GET', which might explain why Get works but POST does not.

Where does this information come from? The answer to this question may lead me to a solution.

I have spent many hours trying to fix this with no luck. Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have been assuming all this time that the 'not allowed' was coming from IIS, and it seems that I was wrong.

My Post method has a parameter of type string. I was assuming that given that my route attribute did not contain a parameter as seen bellow, the parameter would be taken from the request body.

```
[Route("Test")]
[HttpPost]
public string Post(string text)
```

Just to see what happened I added a [FromBody] attribute to this parameter. To my surprise, I got a 415 error instead of the 405.

The research of the 415 error took me to this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

The link tells me that a string parameter is supposed to be part of the uri, and that a string in the body, sent with content-type application/text does not have a default formatter.

I encapsulated the string parameter in a json object, as shown in my new controller, and now the POST works.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Route ("Test")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Response to get Request";
    }

    [Route("Test")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post(StringAsJson stringAsJason)
    {
        return string.Format("Received: '{0}'", stringAsJason.Value);
    }
}

public class StringAsJson
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I went back to my original program and tried to do the same but I still get the 405 error; the difference is that now I know that it is not an IIS issue.

I will open another case if I cannot make my program work.